# Replacing multiple fragmentclass using one fragment view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i am having some trouble understanding and using fragments i have 3 buttons and 1 fragment views .using the buttons as Tabs i am trying to give the fragment a specific class when clicking on a button what i did is this :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Tab1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Tab 1" android:background="@drawable/btn"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Tab2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Tab 2" android:onClick="switchToTab2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Tab3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Tab 3" android:onClick="switchToTab3" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.newproject.fragmentclass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="394dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

java class :

**fragmentclass frt1;

fragmentclass2 frt2;

fragment3class frt3;

FragmentTransaction ft;**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_tabs_exp);

        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        frt1 = new fragmentclass();                
        frt2 = new fragmentclass2();
        frt3 = new fragment3class();

        //ft.add(R.id.fragment1,frt1); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_tabs_exp, menu);
    return true;
}
public void switchToTab2 (View v){
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, frt2).commit();
}

public void switchToTab3 (View v) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, frt3).commit();
}
```

when i click on button2 the fragment class2 is successfully visible except that the default class of the fragment remain visible as well is there anyway to hide it and make the new fragment class active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding fragments in your xml file will make is static through out your application and you can not change it dynamically.

If you want to add Fragments dynamically then you need to add `FrameLayout` in your xml file and load all your fragments dynamically in that layout and replace it one another while loading fragments one after another.

Do below change in your layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="394dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am having troubles when clicking on the button an error is raised saying that : could not execute method of the activity . when i click on tab 1 everything is ok since the frameLayout is empty but when i click on tab2 the error is raised any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `fragment1` from your XML file (so container is empty by default on layout creation time) and add it from code (i.e. in `onCreateView()` of parent fragment or in `onCreate()` of Activity), as fragments cannot be removed out of hierarchy if they are part of XML layout file.

I'd also change container to be `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` if you plan to have just one child in it.

Comment: so i should create the fragment dynamically from the code and not from the xml ?

Comment: +1 for being a little bit faster than me on that one. @Sora this answer is the right answer. Don't add the fragment in the XML but only by code so that the replacement is effective.